# Easiest way to add labeled axes to a grid?

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

I have a grid of images and I' d like to add axes with labels for the \
two dimensions. Here's my data:

```
g = Grid@Table[RandomImage[1, {50, 50}], {i, 5}, {j, 10}];
```

Now I'd like to show with ticks how the x and y axes are increasing. To say the lease, this doesn't do the trick:

```
Labeled[g, {Column[{"Y axis", Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]]}], 
  Column[{Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]], "X axis"}]}, {Left, 
  Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Second try

*Now with better spacing for the axis lines.*

Based on the comments I think this may work for you.

```
imgs = Table[RandomImage[1, {50, 50}], {i, 4}, {j, 7}];
imgs = Transpose @ imgs;

Graphics[
  MapIndexed[Inset[Rasterize@#, #2] &, imgs, {2}] 
  , PlotRange -> Thread[{1/4, 2/3 + Dimensions @ imgs}]
  , Axes -> True
  , Ticks -> Range @ Dimensions @ imgs
  , AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03]
  , AxesOrigin -> {1/4, 1/4}
  , ImageSize -> 420
];

Labeled[%, {"Y axis", "X axis"}, {Left, Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

Note:

- The individual images are fixed size and their spacing is determined by the overall `ImageSize`.  They will overlap if the `ImageSize` is small.

Comment: Nice, but could you make the axes go all the way across and put ticks on the lines at the centers of the images with specific values?

Comment: Kind of like `MatrixPlot[{{1, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]` but with the grid instead of the matrix

Comment: @user5601 Do the items in your grid need to be absolute size (one to one pixel) or is it OK if they are scaled somewhat?  It may be practical to `Inset` them into a plot with ticks.

Comment: It's always nice to Have PixelContrained->1, but that should be fine

Comment: @user5601 Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Gorgeous! Thank you.

Comment: @user5601 You are welcome. :-)

Comment: The margins are a bit tight, not sure how to expand them. Perhaps we need a function Axised[]

Comment: @user5601 Do you mean between the axis lines and the images, or outside on the top and right, or both?

Comment: Between the arrow axis lines and the images

Comment: @user5601 I provided one more example.  Familiarize yourself with the Options of `Graphics` and you should be able to get just about any customization you want.